Empty String returned when i try to decrypt a card number on node app that was encrypted using the same key in the react app
iam using cryptojs on react app to encvrypt a card that i send over the wire to my node app where i decrypt it using the same key. iam pretty sure it was working before but iam not sure. Iam getting an empty string on decryption and i cant figure out what i am doing wrong
in react app
 handleEncrypt =(ccNumber)=>{
        const key = process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_ENCRYPTION_KEY
        const encrypted = window.CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(ccNumber,key.trim()).toString()
        return encrypted;

    }

in config
REACT_APP_SITE_ENCRYPTION_KEY = y$3&g</l1=OrNunxw5{g72lmkX+:<sL^

on the node side
const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');

function decryptor(encryptedCreditCard) {
      const decryptionKey = process.env.DECRYPTION_KEY;
      const decryptedBytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
        encryptedCreditCard,
        decryptionKey,
      );
      const decryptedCreditCard = decryptedBytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    
      return decryptedCreditCard;
    }

any help will be much appreciated

This is a fairly simple code that works as such, see https://jsfiddle.net/uwbqe70h/. The problem is therefore in the data or is environment-specific. Check whether the key material is really identical on both sides and whether the ciphertext generated during encryption really reaches the decryption side uncorrupted. If the problem persists, post sample data for the posted key: plaintext and ciphertext generated on the react side.
